# R: Applying a function to two different tables based on a condition (Spatial Join)

Tags: r, r-sf

I suspect that this is fairly trivial, but I'm also fairly new to R and have not found a solution to this so far.

I have **two** tables of events, A and B, each containing points with spatial information (latitude and longitude) and dates. Both are `sf` objects. Table A has fewer events than table B.

The data in both tables looks like this:

| ID | date | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020/01/01 | 44.62 | 34.88 |

For every point from A, I want to find the nearest neighbor from B - but only for events on *that day*. And then add its ID and the distance to a new column. The function to perform the spatial join is `st_join` from the `nngeo` package and works great.

In other words, I'd want the program to take an event in table A, then take every event on the same day in table B and then apply the st_join function. It should iterate through every event in A and repeat the same procedure.

I think that this would require a `for...if...else` statement, but I can't wrap my head around what it would look like, especially since there are two different tables involved. Like I said, I'm new to R.

My idea so far looks something like this:

```
for (row in AW_sf){
      if (AW_sf$date == OIR_sf$date){
        SpacialJoin <- st_join(AW_sf, OIR_sf, join = st_nn, k = 1)
      } 
      else {
    print ("Done")
  } 
}
```

This does not work, and it also seems wrong. Accordingly, it results in 12 warnings like so:

```
  In `==.default`(AW_sf$date, OIR_sf$date) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In if (AW_sf$date == OIR_sf$date) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I hope I expressed myself somewhat clearly and I'm sorry if something remains unclear. I would be incredibly thankful for any ideas or help!

Comment: You may want `fuzzyjoin::geo_inner_join`.

Comment: The function looks great, thank you! However, I don't know how I can use that function and only have it compare points that are on the same day

Comment: I think you can use `inner_join(tidyr::nest_by(df1, date, .key="dat1"), tidyr::nest_by(df2, date, .key="dat2")) %>% purrr::map2(dat1, dat2, ~ geo_inner_join(...))` or similar. If you aren't familiar with the `tidyr` notion of nesting datasets, then it seems unlikely you're going to have an efficient by-date determinant.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it's not the most elegant or fast solution I suppose, but it's much simpler than I thought it would have to be and it does the trick, using the function r2evans suggested.

```
 EventPairs <- A %>%   geo_join(B, by=c("longitude", "latitude"), unit =
 c("km"), max_dist = 20, distance_col = "distance") %>%   filter(date.x
 == date.y)
```